# Is it possible to make lucene.net ignore case of the field for queries?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have documents indexed with field "GuidId" field and "guidid". How can I make lucene net ignore the case ...so that the following query searches regardless of the case ?

```
TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("GuidId", guidId.ToString()));
```

I don't want to write another query for the documents with fields "guidid" ..i.e. lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, don't have fields names with funky cases.  If you are defining field names dynamically or some such, then you should lowercase them before adding them to the index.  That done, it should be easy enough to keep the query fields' names lowercase as well, and you're in good shape.

If, for whatever reason, you are stuck with this case-sensitive data, you'll be stuck expanding your queries to search all the known permutations of the field name to get all your results.  Something like:

```
Query finalQuery = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(0)
finalQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("GuidId", guidId.ToString())));
finalQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("guidid", guidId.ToString())));
```

[`DisjunctionMaxQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html#DisjunctionMaxQuery%28float%29) would probably be a good choice here, since it only returns the maximum scoring hit among is query collection, rather than possibly compounding scores across multiple hits.

You can also use [`MultiFieldQueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) to similar effect.  I don't believe it uses DisjunctionMax, but it doesn't sound like it would likely be that big a deal in this case.